# Installed package (MiKTeX) not working in TeXmaker

Tags: errors, packages, installing

I've installed some packages using the MiKTeX console, namely exercise.sty and the ams packages, but I cant seem to use some of the functions in these packages. I can't use "\theoremstyle," "\begin{exercise}," or "\newtheoremstyle."

The error code it gives me is "undefined control sequence" for \theoremstyle and "environment exercise undefined" for \begin{exercise}.

I tried defining an exercise environment, but it was in the default style, and I can't seem to change it.

Here's my code:

```
    \documentclass[11pt]{book}

    \usepackage{amsmath}
    \usepackage{amsfonts}
    \usepackage{amssymb}
    \usepackage{exercise}

    \begin{document}

    %This section defines an exercise environment with the remark style
    %but the \theoremstyle throws an error.
    %\theoremstyle{remark}
    %\newtheorem{exercise}[subsection]

    \section{Introduction}
    Text Block
    \section{The Real Number System}
    Text Block
    \section{Algebraic Structure}
    Text Block
    \subsection*{Exercises}
    \begin{exercise}
    Text
    \end{exercise}

    \end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

`\theoremstyle` is a `amsthm` command. So you should load this package. `\newtheorem` has two mandatory commands. The exercise package defines and environment `Exercise` (with uppercase E). This here compiles without error, but I don't know if the output is the one you want.

```
\documentclass[11pt]{book}

    \usepackage{amsmath}
    \usepackage{amsthm}
    \theoremstyle{remark}
    \newtheorem{exercise}{Exercise}


    \usepackage{amsfonts}
    \usepackage{amssymb}
    \usepackage{exercise}


    \begin{document}

    \section{Introduction}
    Text Block
    \section{The Real Number System}
    Text Block
    \section{Algebraic Structure}
    Text Block
    \subsection*{Exercises}
    \begin{exercise}
    Text
    \end{exercise}

    \end{document}
```